# Filming light in slo mo

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, home-experiment

So I was thinking of a cool video I could make when I thought of filming a video of me turning on a light. I thought that if you film yourself turning on a light and slo mo that video enough times (theoretically I you had a camera that could record that many frames per second)will you be able to see light moving through your videos view, or will it just turn into a slide show?
Thanks in advance for any answers
(PS if this has already been done please give me a link to the video.)

Comment: How would you "see light moving" when the light has not yet reached you?

Comment: When the light goes through the frame of view

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yXHWJ4iUlZs. However this was done by repeating the light exposure a million times or so and taking photo shots at different exposure times.

Comment: @Marcel: Wow! That's cool! But now I want a femtosecond laser for christmas...

Answer (score 2):

Light moves at about a foot per nanosecond, or a meter every three nanoseconds. In order to capture it propagating across a room over a few frames, you would need to gather something like a *billion* frames per second. No consumer camera -- indeed no camera on Earth -- is capable of this.

Now there have been people playing with "[fempto-photography](http://web.media.mit.edu/~raskar/trillionfps/)," but they use a hack. They switch on the light many, many, many times, in exactly the same way, and each time record just one frame at a very precise time. They then put all the frames into a single movie. That is, they leverage precision *timing* rather than raw *speed*, the former of which *is* achievable.

Note though that the equipment is still beyond the consumer level. You need a shutter speed fast enough so as to not blur a single frame, as well as nanosecond-resolution triggering.

Comment: The fastest camera I am aware of that can do single event recording is the [Imacon 200](http://www.vision-systems.com/articles/print/volume-8/issue-2/features/profile-in-vision-solutions/imaging-system-freezes-projectile-collision.html) capable of recording 16 consecutive frames with 200 Mfps effective rate - you would see light move 1.5 m between frames...